# How to make cluster with playframework application

Tags: scalability, distributed-transactions, playframework-2.5, clusterize

I want to deploy a playframework application in version 2.5 with injection on several servers,

How i can do , i don't found any documentation on the process..

is there specifics configuration, is there any things to do with transaction ? with cache?